# different desktop on different monitors (win10)

Tags: windows-10

my ideal scenario would be that I can set up virtual desktops on my two monitors in windows 10.

One will have whatever I'm working on, say Word and Excel and the other will have communications, say Outlook and Skype set next to each other.

I would then be able to use a shortcut key to rotate the desktops between the two monitors and back again. That way, the layout on each will be preserved

thanks

Comment: Doesn't Windows 10 already come with that?

Comment: not that I can find out.  You can have a desktop spread across two monitors and you can switch between desktops, but you can't have an independent desktop on each monitor.